# How do you make an email go to spam

Tags: php, html, email, spam

I am writing a script for a film. I have a basic script that sends an HTML email to two sets of emails. On the form you enter in the event information and that information gets sent to two lists of users, the "Desired Guests" and the "Undesired Guests" they both get the same exact HTML email however I need the email for the "Undesired Guests" to go to the spam folder. So what I did was for the "Undesired Guest" email list was insert a bunch of spam content into the body of the email as I need this email to send to the spam folder. The "Desired Guests" email should go to the inbox just fine (as is currently is)

Is there any way I can make the "Undesired Guests" email to go spam for sure? Can I send the email through an outside server with a different IP and bad reputation to make these emails go to spam?

Any input would be a great help.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $event = strtoupper($_POST['event']);
        $host = strtoupper($_POST['host']);
        $location = strtoupper($_POST['location']);
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $start_time = $_POST['start_time'];
        $end_time = $_POST['end_time'];
        $msg = ucfirst($_POST['msg']);
        $mainuser = $_POST['mainuser'];
        $wrong_user = $_POST['wrong_user'];

    if($mainuser!='') {
        $user_mail = explode(",", $mainuser);
        $count = count($user_mail);
        $sub = "You're Invited";
        $sender = "info@cdell.me";

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $mail_to = $user_mail[$i];
            $mail_body =
            '<style type="text/css">
        <!--
       .style1 {color: #8f8f8f}
        -->
        </style>
        </head>

        <body style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:#f5f5f5; line-    height:24px;">
        <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <tr>
            <td><img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/header.png" width="600" height="200" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
    <td height="50" bgcolor="#ececec"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>


      </tr>
    </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#e0e0e0" style="padding:20px; font-size:16px; color:#8f8f8f" align="center">
    <p><strong>'.$event.'</strong></p>
    <p><strong>When:</strong> '.$date.' &nbsp; '.$start_time.' - '.$end_time.'</p>
    <p><strong>Where:</strong> '.$location.'</p>
    <p><strong>Message From '.$host.':</strong> <br /> '.$msg.'</p><br /><br /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#e0e0e0" align="center"><a href="#" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; background:#2ecc71; text-decoration:none;">RSVP!</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td height="30" bgcolor="#e0e0e0">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><table width="520" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

          <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>




          <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #2ecc71">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
         <td><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#2ecc71">
            <tr>
            <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="240">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="240">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

             <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="240">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="240">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="40">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>';


        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "to:".$ro['emai_addrs']."\r\n";
        $headers .= "from: ".$sender."\r\n";
        mail($mail_to, $sub, $mail_body, $headers); 
        //echo $mail_body;
}
}


    if($wrong_user!='') {
        $user_mail=explode(",", $wrong_user);
        $count=count($user_mail);
        $sub="INVITATION";
        $sender="";
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
            $mail_to = $user_mail[$i];
            $mail_body =
            '<style type="text/css">
            <!--
            .style1 {color: #8f8f8f}
            -->
            </style>
            </head>

            <body style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:#f5f5f5; line-height:24px;">
            <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
              <tr>
                <td><img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/header.png" width="600" height="200" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="50" bgcolor="#ececec"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>


                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#e0e0e0" style="padding:20px; font-size:16px; color:#8f8f8f" align="center">
                <p><strong>'.$event.'</strong></p>
                <p><strong>When:</strong> '.$date.' &nbsp; '.$start_time.' - '.$end_time.'</p>
                <p><strong>Where:</strong> '.$location.'</p>
                <p><strong>Message From '.$host.':</strong> <br /> '.$msg.'</p><br /><br /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#e0e0e0" align="center"><a href="#" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; background:#2ecc71; text-decoration:none;">RSVP!</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" bgcolor="#e0e0e0">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="40" style="color:white;">&nbsp;9 INCH PENIS, SPAM EMAIL, THIS IS SPAM, 10 INCH PENIS, VIAGRA, PENIS ENLARGMENT, NIGERAIAN $$$100,000,000.00, FREE CREDIT REPORT, FREE 10 INCH PENIS ENLARGER, CLICK HERE FOR FREE VIAGRA WIN A FREE CAR!!! WORTH 10K$$$, NO CREDIT CHECK PAYDAY LOANS, CAR LOANS, INHERIT $10,675,981.98 US CURRENCY FROM NIGERIAN PRINCE US BANK ACCOUNT NEEDED</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><table width="520" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>




                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #2ecc71">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="color:23cc71;"><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style="color:23cc71;">
                  <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp;
                    9 INCH PENIS, SPAM EMAIL, THIS IS SPAM, 10 INCH PENIS, VIAGRA, PENIS ENLARGMENT, NIGERAIAN $$$100,000,000.00, FREE CREDIT REPORT, FREE 10 INCH PENIS ENLARGER, CLICK HERE FOR FREE VIAGRA</td>
                    <td width="240" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp;WIN A FREE CAR!!! WORTH 10K$$$, NO CREDIT CHECK PAYDAY LOANS, CAR LOANS, INHERIT $10,675,981.98 US CURRENCY FROM NIGERIAN PRINCE US BANK ACCOUNT NEEDED</td>
                    <td width="40" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="240" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="40" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>

                    <td width="40" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp; 9 INCH PENIS, SPAM EMAIL, THIS IS SPAM, 10 INCH PENIS, VIAGRA, PENIS ENLARGMENT, NIGERAIAN $$$100,000,000.00, FREE CREDIT REPORT, FREE 10 INCH PENIS ENLARGER, CLICK HERE FOR FREE VIAGRA</td>
                    <td width="240" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="40" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="240" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp; 9 INCH PENIS, SPAM EMAIL, THIS IS SPAM, 10 INCH PENIS, VIAGRA, PENIS ENLARGMENT, NIGERAIAN $$$100,000,000.00, FREE CREDIT REPORT, FREE 10 INCH PENIS ENLARGER, CLICK HERE FOR FREE VIAGRA</td>
                    <td width="40" bgcolor="#2ecc71" style=" color:#2ecc71;" align="center">&nbsp;
                       <!-- Spam Pixel Images -->
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel1.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel2.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel3.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel4.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel5.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel6.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel7.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel8.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel9.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel10.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel11.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel12.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel13.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel14.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel15.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel16.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel17.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel18.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel19.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.cdell.me/invite-site/green-pixel20.png" />
                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </body>';

        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "to:".$ro['emai_addrs']."\r\n";
        $headers .= "from: ".$sender."\r\n";
        mail($mail_to, $sub, $mail_body, $headers); 
        //echo $mail_body;
}
}

        $var = "Invitation Sent Successfully";


}
```

Comment: lol, that's an unexpected question :) I guess there is no sure-fire way to make a message go to the spam folder. Just take a checklist of mistakes you usually want to *avoid*, and make as many of them as possible. Sending them from a server with bad reputation would surely go a long way, as well as a `from:` address that doesn't resolve to the outgoing mail server

Comment: @Pekka웃 You beat me to saying the same comment LOL! Usually it's the other way around!

Comment: Remove all your headers except `$headers = "from: ".$sender."\r\n";` that could fire it up. And add the word "unsubscribe" in there somewhere. Could work.

Comment: @charlietfl OOuuhhhh... creepy.

Comment: `$enhancement_products = array('viagra, cialis');` --- `if(in_array){ dump it! ; }`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe some keywords like free credit score, home mortgage refinance, mentioning cialis or other perscription drugs will almost certainly get you in there.

Comment: @JohnConde: Not so. That question is the other way around. As I understand it, OP **wants** the email to get marked as spam; not the other way around.

Comment: Yeah I need the email for the "Undesired Guests" to go to spam and the email for the "Desired Guests" to go to the inbox which it currently is so that isn't the problem. I have added a ton of spam content in the body which I plan on adding more of. I also added a ton of 1x1 pixel images for the email to download since I hear that if you have more images then text content, you are likely to be marked as spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding X-Spam related headers, so as to masquerade as something that went through and got caught by Spam Assassin?

If not, a few headers you might want to look into:

- X-Spam-Score
- X-Spam-Level
- X-Spam-Status
- X-Spam-Flag
- X-Spam-Report

More info:

https://www.lamphost.com/Knowledge_Base/What_headers_are_added_to_emails_that_are_scanned_by_SpamAssassintm

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of things you can do to get it marked as spam, however, if someone has you listed as a 'safe-sender', 100% guarantees may be out of the question.

There are plenty of keywords you can use, they don't need to be shady words either. In the past, I've had issues just using large money amounts, exclamation points and the word 'free'.

[Litmus](http://litmus.com/email-testing) is a great tool for checking your spam scores in different mail clients. For most spam software, it is an accumulative score, so you will easily be able to identify the worst (or in your case best) culprets.

Answer (score 0):

Just **BLACKLIST** your Ip address,
also each blacklisting servers has their own listing criteria that may include **technical listings, policy listings, and evidence based listings**. Technical listings are those that occur mostly from mail server configuration issues such as missing or incorrect reverse DNS records, missing on incorrect banner greetings, and mail servers operating in IP address space that an ISP has specified that mail servers should not be operating in. Policy listings are those based on an operator that does not wish to receive email from certain countries, or ISPs, or has a history of no honoring unsubscribe requests. Evidence based listings are those where the operator has receive direct (or indirect) evidence that an IP address has been involved in sending unsolicited emails.